# Storing specific fields from multiple files into an array

Tags: perl

To store multiple files into an array I usually use:

```
@files = glob("*.txt");
my @ID;
for my $file(@files) {
   open IN, '<', $file or die "$!";
   push @ID, $_ while (<IN>);
}
```

Which works fine.

However, what can I do if I don't wish to push the entirety of `$_` and store only specific fields instead?

I've tried splitting `$_` and pushing specific fields e.g. `$F[2]` as well as splitting `$_` and rejoining specific elements of it and pushing the result:

```
@files = glob("*.txt");
my @ID;
for my $file(@files) {
   open IN, '<', $file or die "$!";
   my @F = split(' ', $_);
   $fields = join "\t", @F[0,1,2,3];
   push @ID, $fields while (<IN>);
}
```

However `@ID` is empty when printed when using the second block of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tried to split $_ before $_ was set.  You need to move that code into the while loop:

```
@files = glob("*.txt");
my @ID;
for my $file(@files) {
   open IN, '<', $file or die "$!";
   while (<IN>) {
      my @F = split(' ', $_);
      $fields = join "\t", @F[0,1,2,3];
      push @ID, $fields;
   }
}
```

Comment: `split ( ' ', $_)` is the default case for `split;`  (Although please don't use single letter variable names)

Answer (score 1):

It's not empty.

```
$VAR1 = [
          "\t\t\t",
          "\t\t\t",
          ...
          "\t\t\t"
        ];
```

But it doesn't contain what you want either.

You're trying to split each line you read, but you do so before you even read from the file! Fix:

```
while (<IN>) {
   my @F = split(' ', $_);
   my $fields = join "\t", @F[0,1,2,3];
   push @ID, $fields;
}
```

*Always* use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`! This would have found your problem.

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in split at a.pl line 7.
```

Answer (score 1):

Those code fragments are more neatly written like this

```
my @ID;

for my $file ( glob '*.txt' ) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
    push @ID, <$fh>;
}
```

and

```
my @ID;

for my $file ( glob '*.txt' ) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
    push @ID, join "\t", (split)[0 .. 3] while <$fh>;
}
```

Note that I have used *lexical* file handles, which will be closed implicitly when they go out of scope, and so avoided the need to write an explicit `close`

In the former case each array element still has a newline appended which may need to be removed with `chomp @ID`

In the latter case it may well be preferable to store each list of fields as an array instead of combining them into a single string, which may then need to be split again later to access the fields separately. That would look like

```
push @ID, [ (split)[0..3] ] while <$fh>;
```